# Problema al "importar" tabla desde PHP a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

que tal, estoy realizando un proyecto con php estructurado en MVC. Necesito hacer que una de mis tablas en MySQL sea actualizada por un usuario administrador desde la página web, para esto generé una estructura AJAX la cual es la siguiente:

**index.php<->update.js<->update.php<->updatemodel.php**

con esta estructura, el administrador puede subir un archivo de tipo CSV e indicar cual es el separador de sus columnas (',', ';',etc.) desde la interfaz de usuario.

El archivo que sube el usuario ya viene preparado para insertarse en la tabla, con codificación utf-8, columnas separadas por ";" y los registros no vienen encerrados en comillas.Cuando subo este archivo al servidor desde phpmyadmin directamente importándolo, no me da ningún problema así que se puede descartar que el error ,que cometo abajo, provenga de este archivo.

primero recibo los datos con el archivo update.php:

```
function actualizar(){
    $archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];
    $separation = $_POST['separation'];

    $nombre_archivo = $archivo['name'];
    $tipo_archivo = explode('.', $nombre_archivo);

    if(strtolower(end($tipo_archivo)) == 'csv'){
      $filename = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
      $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
      $insertar = $this->model->Actualizar($handle, $separation);
      if($insertar){
        echo "Se insertaron todos los datos correctamente";
      }else{
        echo "No se insertaron los datos correctamente";
      }
    }else{
      echo "El tipo de archivo es invalido";
    }
  }
```

Luego, el método que halle, que se no es muy eficiente, para "importar" la tabla que el usuario sube, es este:

archivo updatemodel.php

-primero borro todos los datos que existen en la tabla, luego se inserta registro por registro y finalmente borro un registro el cual es la cabecera del archivo CSV que se exporta por defecto.

```
public function Actualizar($archivo, $separador){

    try{
      $delete = "DELETE FROM tabla";
      $status = $this->con->prepare($delete);
      $status->execute();

      if($status){
          while(($data = fgetcsv($archivo, 2000, $separador)) !== FALSE){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ". constant('TABLA_ACTUAL') ."(RFC, NOMBRE, CLAVEADS, TIPOMOV,CAUSA,CATEGO,TIPOPZA, TIPONOM, FECHAINI, FECHATERM,TIPOHOR,CLAVEASIG,GRUPO,HR1,SALON1,HR2,SALON2,HR3,SALON3,HR4,SALON4,HR5,SALON5,HRTEOR,HRPRAC,HRAPOY,HRTOT,MARCA,HRSNOM,FECHACT) VALUE(";
            for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++){
              $sql .= "'$data[$i]'";
              if($i != 29){
                $sql .= ",";
              }
            }
            $sql .= ")";
            $ejecutar = $this->con->prepare($sql);
            $ejecutar->execute();
          }

          $delete_bad = "DELETE FROM ". constant('TABLA_ACTUAL') ." WHERE RFC = '?RFC' OR NOMBRE = 'NOMBRE'";
          $execute =$this->con->prepare($delete_bad);
          $execute->execute();

          return true;  
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**ERROR**
El problema está en que cuando corro el programa con XAMPP, funciona, pero cuando lo subo a mi servidor linux, funciona hasta el paso de borrar los datos de la tabla, de ahí no pasa y retorna false

```
try{
  $delete = "DELETE FROM tabla";
  $status = $this->con->prepare($delete);
  $status->execute();

  if($status){
```

En primera pensé que el usuario MySQL que usaba no tenia los permisos necesarios para borrar, si los tenia. Mi sospecha es que el archivo CSV que sube el usuario, no logra guardarse en la carpeta temporal del servidor pero es una sospecha poco fundamentada.

**PREGUNTAS**

- ¿Por que no me permite insertar los datos?
- ¿Hay otro método que me permita importar una tabla desde una query SQL en php?

Les agradecería muchísimo cualquier ayuda que puedan proporcionar y el que hallan dedicado tiempo para mi problema. Gracias y hasta pronto.

Comment: ¿No estás capturando y mostrando el mensaje de error en el `try`? Ahí debería decirte lo que ocurre.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad no entendía muy bien como funcionaba la estructura try/catch, retorne el error y pude ver que era algo de mis datos y SQL, gracias por la respuesta 